# Intellij IDEA REST Client file uploading

Tags: spring, rest, intellij-idea

I am trying to upload file through Intellij IDEA REST Client. I choose "File to upload (multipart/form-data)" and choose file to send. What is parameter name of this file? In my Sprint Controller i use this code

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/{id}/photo")
public void setCover(@PathVariable int id,
                     @RequestParam MultipartFile file) {
    System.out.println(file.getName());
}
```

I also tried different names, such as "file", "fileToSend", "File to send" for @RequestParam, but Spring always cant find MultipartFile paramater.

Comment: Can you add your error log?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @nyxz No, i just found another rest client (for Google Chrome) in which i can set a parameter name of multipart file. I still don't know how set it in Intellij Rest Client.

Comment: Ran into the same problem. Using a debugger, it appears that the name is actually the filename itself. Since there is no way for the controller to know this in advance, it can't be handled.

Answer (score 24):

I use the following code which works for me:

```
POST http://localhost:9003/goods/add HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary

--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file.csv"

// The 'input.txt' file will be uploaded
< /Users/xing/Desktop/file.csv
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="advertType"

1
--boundary

// The method in the Spring controller
public Xxxx add(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Long advertType) {
```

For more information, please refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/exploring-http-syntax.html#use-multipart-form-data

Comment: I did the same and REST client return 400 status code.

Comment: This solution worked for me but i wasnt able to put a code here, hence added a new reply to this question to support this answer.

Comment: hello, this didn't work for me until I added `--boundary--` at the end, any way thank you so much for your time

Answer (score 8):

File upload is not allowed due to security concern, not for application running on local machine. This solution worked for me. Its based on the comment by vincent.

See below:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/test HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=WebAppBoundary

--WebAppBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="param1"; filename="myfile.csv"
Content-Type: application/csv

 // below will the path to the file (i.e. myfile.csv)
< C:/users/user/data/sample/myfile.csv
--WebAppBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="param2"

 // value of param2
test
--WebAppBoundary

###
```

Answer (score 2):

in a `.http` file, just press `<Ctrl>+j`, idea will popup live template items, then input `fptr`, idea will complete the example code

[image]