# How to send a POST request with a file in raw text and receive in Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring, request, http-post

I'm trying to send a POST request using InteliJ's HTTP client and I'm not receiving it correctly.
I want to send an object and a file in the request, and receive in a Spring Boot's controller as a Request Body parameter.

This is the request:

```
POST http://localhost:7000/api/reports/annex/save/307
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "annex": {
    "id": "",
    "reportId": "307",
    "title": "TEST FILE",
    "description": "TEST DESCRIPTION",
    "creationDate": "",
    "document_path": ""
  },
  "file": "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"
}
```

And this is my controller receiving data:
[image]

As you see, the object annex is correctly received, but File object is NULL.
Someone knows whats wrong with the request?

Thanks!

Comment: This should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/49991403/10691359 or https://github.com/GSSwain/file-upload-ajax-sample ?

Comment: In this example is using a fronted to do it, I need to do without it, any idea? @Pilpo

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34384650/intellij-idea-rest-client-file-uploading

Comment: I've never used multiple @RequestBody params before. A quick Google search shows it is possible, but it would be easier to wrap 'annex' and 'file' within a single object.